# Is NewtonSoft not supported for UWP 10.1?

Tags: asp.net, uwp, json.net, aspnetboilerplate, xamarin.uwp

We have an **Xamarin** project that shares code with *android* and *ios* projects.
We plan To extend this sharing by creating and targeting an **UWP** project.
So to test portability of my project to *UWP* i used the [**.net portability analyzer** extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) in visual studio.

After running it, I get this Portability summary:

```
<h2 _locid="SummaryTitle">
      <a name="Portability Summary"></a>Portability Summary
</h2>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Assembly</th>
            <th>UWP,Version=v10.1</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><strong><a href="#Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Mobile.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
                <span class="assembly-name">Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Mobile.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</span>
                    <span class="assembly-tfm">(.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)</span>
            </a></strong></td>
                <td class="text-center">99.67%</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

which means that the project is 99.67% compatible with UWP 10.1.

In detail I get this:

```
   <table class="table_portability_details">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th>Target type</th>
                        <th>UWP,Version=v10.1</th>
                        <th>Recommended changes</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert</td>
                        <td class="IconErrorEncoded" title="Not supported"></td>             <td></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left:2em"> DeserializeObject``1(System.String)</td>
                            <td class="IconErrorEncoded" title="Not supported"></td>                <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left:2em">SerializeObject(System.Object)</td>
                            <td class="IconErrorEncoded" title="Not supported"></td>                                <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

which describe problems of not supporting **Newtonsoft**.

Do you have an idea on how to fix that if it is possible?

## Update

I did as @Stefan Wick MSFT suggested  , i added an UWP project and used "**16299**" as a minor version:

[image: minimum version uwp]

I still getting the same problem ! ?

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: ok i will updated with html format instead of image

Comment: what are you using for your references nuget or you reference directly your dll in project ?

Comment: Can you clarify more your question please. the project isn't from scratch it's based on [aspNetZero](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Getting-Started-Angular) ,but i can tell you that under **\*.Mobile.Droid** and **\*.Mobile.Ios** there is refrences to nuget packges(Abp,System.xml...)

Comment: What is the minversion of your UWP project? In order to use .NET standard 2.0 libraries your minversion needs to be at least 16299. In case you need to support a lower minversion you'd have to use a different/older JSON library that won't require .NET standard 2.0.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I didn't add a UWP project yet , i am testing portability to UWP 10.1. you have mentionned minversion of uwp to be at least 16299 ? i only see that there is 8.0 8.1 until 10.1 versions of UWP ?

Comment: if UWP version is Windows 10 version then i have 1809 version with OS Build version 17763.379

Comment: I don't know what actual version 10.1 refers to (poor choice of that analyzer tool to make up their own versioning scheme …). The thing to understand is that a UWP project has two versions: minversion and targetversion. The targetversion for you may be 17763, but the minversion determines what libraries you can use. Once you add the UWP project and check the project properties you can set the minversion to 16299 (if it's not already set to that) and you will be fine using Newtonsoft. More about UWP versions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT even after adding your suggestion , the .net probability analyzer still rendering the same issue

Comment: Are you saying the Newtonsoft library actually doesn't work for you? Or that the tool still gives you a warning? The library is being used in numerous UWP projects in production today. I am not familiar with the portability analyzer tool, but I think it's possible that this warning is a false positive.

Comment: the tool still giving the warning. maybe as you said it's a false warning so the .Net team should check this issue !